# Google ActivityRecognitionApi IN_VEHICLE false positives

Tags: android, activity-recognition

We have an application that uses Google's ActivityRecognitionAPI and it works well for determining if a driver is driving, stopped, or when he hops out of vehicle and transitions to ON_FOOT.

However, we see a lot of false positives for IN_VEHICLE.  With higher end devices it is much worse.  We see them when users are typing emails or texts or even just navigating through device content.

Are we unique in seeing this?  Do others have strategies for defending the false positives?

Answer (score 0):

This may come a little late but I have noticed that as well. I suppose it is because sometimes the way you move just looks like a vehicle's movement. I have noticed that sometimes I have similar false positives with on_bicycle. I have also noticed how often this happens because I am holding the phone in my hand and assuming an unusual position (e.g. I am retrieving my wallet from the pocket while walking).